# Lodash rounding precision

Tags: javascript, rounding, percentage, lodash, floating-point-precision

I'm trying to display a number as a percent by using `_.round` and then by multiplying the number by 100. For some reason, when I multiply the rounded number, the precision gets messed up. Here's what it looks like:

```
var num = 0.056789,
    roundingPrecision = 4,
    roundedNum = _.round(num, roundingPrecision),
    percent = (roundedNum * 100) + '%';

console.log(roundedNum); // 0.0568
console.log(percent); // 5.680000000000001%
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whbb29nm/)

Why is the 0.000000000000001 added to the number after multiplying by 100?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks @JamesDonnelly!

Comment: Please provide a succinct answer to your own question, @TimPerkins. The referenced post might cover the subject, but it is unclear how exactly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is due to the fact that numbers are represented internally as binary numbers with limited precision.

See also ["Is floating point math broken?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

---

**Is floating point math broken?**

> 0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3
> -> false
>
> 0.1 + 0.2 -> 0.30000000000000004
>
> Any ideas why this happens?

Which got the answer:

> Binary [floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) math is like this.  In most programming languages, it is based on the [IEEE 754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_formats). JavaScript uses 64-bit floating point representation, which is the same as Java's `double`.  The crux of the problem is that numbers are represented in this format as a whole number times a power of two; rational numbers (such as `0.1`, which is `1/10`) whose denominator is not a power of two cannot be exactly represented.

---

To get the correct outcome in your case, you need to round *after* all the arithmetic:

```js
var num = 0.056789,
  roundingPrecision = 4,
  roundedNum = _.round(num * 100, roundingPrecision),
  percent = roundedNum + '%';

console.log(percent); // 5.6789%
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Pedantic, but technically, to get the answer the original question asker wanted, you would need to do `roundingPrecision - 2` (with appropriate bounding guards). Otherwise, you've increased the amount of precision desired.